# How do I create integration tests when leveraging Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, integration-testing, xamarin.forms

How do I create integration tests when leveraging Xamarin.Forms?

Specifically, I do NOT want to rely on UI automation to test integration between the components of a system (i.e. database using SQLite).

I want my integration tests to target the layer beneath the UI.

Comment: Personally I've found this to be a pain point.  Would you be able to accomplish your testing using Xamarin's unit testing apps?  They are limited to Android and iOS, but that might be sufficient.  Xamarin Studio and Visual Studio have a unit testing project (Android and iOS specific).  It creates a separate app that is a test runner, which can run tests targeting your shared code (PCL or other).

Answer (score 0):

For this I would recommend xUnit (there are others as well), that can test directly against PCL's. The native projects should be fairly empty and your ViewModels and Views should be void of most code, which means you can test directly on the Model and below.

Place a mock ISQLite DB connection to test the code without the SQLite DB, or place another one in that actually connects to a local SQLite DB, either way.

xUnit Project

https://github.com/xunit/devices.xunit

Though download the packages from NuGet, its easier. Then the test can also be run from VS which is a nice addition.